# How to reset all other nested data inside parent onclick Alpine.js

Tags: javascript, html, alpine.js

I have multiple groups and multiple choices inside each group. When I click on a choice inside a group the `groupcount` should always + 1 and the clicked `choicecount` should be set to 1 while the other `choicecount`'s inside the group should be reset to 0.

I have tried using `$dispatch` to reset all `choicecount`'s inside the group to 0 before setting `choicecount = 1` and `groupcount++`, but `$dispatch` doesn't seem to trigger the other nested `choicecount`'s inside the group.

For example, in the snippet below (Group 1):
Only one of `G1 Option 1`, `G1 Option 2`, `G1 Option 3` should be allowed to equal 1 at a time.
If `G1 Option 2` = 1 then `G1 Option 1` and `G1 Option 3` should = 0. The `groupcount`'s are working fine.

Note: This is stripped down, radio buttons aren't suitable for the feature I'm creating and I'm not using `x-for` because these groups and choices will be generated from a PHP loop. The number of groups and choices will vary.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<!-- GROUP 1 -->
<div x-data="{ groupcount: 0 }">
  <label>Group 1 Count</label>
  <input x-model="groupcount" type="text">

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G1 Option 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G1 Option 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G1 Option 3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<hr>

<!-- GROUP 2 -->
<div x-data="{ groupcount: 0 }">
  <label>Group 2 Count</label>
  <input x-model="groupcount" type="text">

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G2 Option 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G2 Option 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<hr>

<!-- GROUP 3 -->
<div x-data="{ groupcount: 0 }">
  <label>Group 3 Count</label>
  <input x-model="groupcount" type="text">

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G3 Option 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:resetAllCountsInGroup="choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('resetAllCountsInGroup'),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G3 Option 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three issues with the example. First, due to event bubbling, we need to use the [`.window` modifier](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#window) on the event listeners. Second, camelCasing is not supported inside HTML attributes, so we need to use dashes in the event name (or use the [`.camel` modifier](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#camel)), I will use `reset-group` in the example. The last issue is that the resetting event now acts on every group, so we need to limit its scope to the current group. For that, I added a `groupid` property to each group, which is unique and it is included in the event as well, so we can check its value inside the event listener with `if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0` before resetting a group.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>

<div x-data="{ groupcount: 0, groupid: 1 }">
  <label>Group 1 Count</label>
  <input x-model="groupcount" type="text">

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:reset-group.window="if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('reset-group', groupid),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G1 Option 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:reset-group.window="if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('reset-group', groupid),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G1 Option 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:reset-group.window="if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('reset-group', groupid),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G1 Option 3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div x-data="{ groupcount: 0, groupid: 2 }">
  <label>Group 2 Count</label>
  <input x-model="groupcount" type="text">

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:reset-group.window="if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('reset-group', groupid),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G2 Option 1
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:reset-group.window="if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('reset-group', groupid),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G2 Option 2
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div x-data="{ choicecount: 0 }">
    <div x-on:reset-group.window="if (groupid == $event.detail) choicecount=0">
      <input x-model="choicecount" type="text">
      <button type="button" x-on:click="$dispatch('reset-group', groupid),choicecount=1,groupcount++">
        G2 Option 3
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```